# Kaminari and Ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack, kaminari

Im using the ransack gem which performs queries and shows relevant posts. Now I'm trying to implement the kaminari gem to show 12 posts per page.

here is my controller:

```
def index
    @search = Post.search(params[:q])
    @post = @search.result(distinct: true)

    @post = Post.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(12)
end
```

the problem I have is when i click on the search button, it does not work, the posts same the same, nothing gets updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't run the kaminari paging on `Post`... that just ignores the ransack results and creates a new collection.
Run paging on the `@post` collection.

```
def index
    @search = Post.search(params[:q])
    @post = @search.result(distinct: true)

    @post = @post.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(12)
end
```

Comment: still does not seem to work, it creates the pages and limits 12 per page but when i click on the next page or try to make a query nothing loads, it stays the same?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're passing in "params[:page]"

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the answer, rather than use the `kaminari gem`, i switched over to `will_paginate gem` and changed my controllers index method to:

```
@search = Post.search(params[:q])
@posts = @search.result(distinct: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page])
```